# ImageButton animation not applied to all states

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton whose image rotates with the device orientation so that the image/ button is always horizontal (note that the rotations is handled manually, not through the activity life-cycle).

This all works great, except when the user presses the button (state is pressed), the 90' rotation is lost temporarily.

Button Animation;

```
<rotate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="200" android:fillAfter="true">
</rotate>
```

The image button drawable;

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_go_back_pressed" />

    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_go_back_disabled" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_go_back_normal" />

</selector>
```

Loading the animation;

```
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.button_rotate90);
```

And then when the device orientation changes;

```
    case MessageQue.SET_TO_PORTRAIT:
        inPortrait = true;
        for (View ib : buttonsToAnimate) {
            if (ib instanceof TextView) {
                ib.startAnimation(cntPortraitAnim);
            } else {
                ib.startAnimation(btnPortraitAnim);
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why, and more importantly, how to fix it?

Comment: It might be the fact that you are using a view animation which isn't going to update the clickable area. I recommend trying out a property animation.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent pointer Whitney - this solved visibility issues I was having as well.
All the above code has been replaced with;

```
case MessageQue.SET_TO_LANDSCAPE:
    for (View ib : buttonsToAnimate) ib.animate().rotation(0).setDuration(200);
    break;
case MessageQue.SET_TO_PORTRAIT:
    for (View ib : buttonsToAnimate) ib.animate().rotation(-90).setDuration(200);
    break;
```

Thanks.